# Get list of urls of a google research?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to get quickly the list of urls of a search google in the form of list!

### Currently, my program looks like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

keyword = input("keyword: ")
url = "http://www.google.fr/search?" + keyword
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

listlink = list(set(r.html.absolute_links))
```

---

But this program is slow to run. I would like to know if there is a faster way to get the urls list of a google search (with beautifulSoup or others..) ?

The google search API has a request limit, which can be problematic for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, and your code didn't run on my machine.  I'll take a stab at this though.  Maybe this is what you are after...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '10'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```